# What is the intention of the class `Model` in this code snippets?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a code base written by someone else. a `Model` class is defined in the following snippet, but I can not figure out why the writer defined this class. What is the intention to define this class other that using plain `Object`? What is the pattern here? Thank you very much!

```
const models = {}

export default class Model {
  constructor() {
    this._type = this.constructor.name
    if (!models[this._type]) {
      models[this._type] = this.constructor.prototype
    }
  }
}

const model = object => {
  if (!object) {
    return object
  }
  if (object._type && object._type != object.constructor.name) {
    object.__proto__ = models[object._type]
  }
  (typeof object == "object") && Object.values(object).forEach(v => {
    model(v)
  })
  return object
}
```

Its usage:

`class xxxModel extends Model { ... }`.

## updated

and there are many occurrences of the following usage pattern:

```
const refreshData = function (...args) {
  // do something to update UI.
  const data = args[0]
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => model(this.data[key]))
}
```

Comment: it is kind of useless in my eyes. There is only an attribute `_type` set to that `Model` and this is appended to `__proto__` in the function below if the given object is not `falsy`. If `object` is really an object this `model` method is called for each attribute in the given `object` parameter

Comment: this is way too abstract. Currently I don't know what the achievment of this should be